# Dimensions in geometry

Tags: geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of dimensions. Here's what wikipedia has to say:

> In physics and mathematics, the dimension of a mathematical space (or object) is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point within it.

Here's my problem:

Imagine a **plane ABCD** on a cartesian coordinate grid. **Line segment CD** has **point E** plotted on it at (1.5, 2). Given that two coordinates were required to place **point E** on **line segment CD**, shouldn't that make **line segment CD** a two dimensional object? Or am I looking at it the wrong way? Really this seems to be just a question of whether a line becomes a two-dimensional object if it is placed in a two-dimensional setting/space.

[Here is an image to help you visualize the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucTD6.jpg)

This also has other implications elsewhere. Does a plane face on a three-dimensional hexahedron become 3D as well because 3 coordinates are needed to place a point inside the plane? And so on.

Thank-you!

Comment: You are talking about a square (or a rectangl)  ABCD.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the word 'minimum' in "the minimum number of coordinates required...".

In the example you give you deliberately choose an inefficient way to determine the point, namely using two coordinates since the line lives in an ambient plane. But, you could do better. Choose any arbitrary point on the line, call it $p_0$. Then you can describe any other point on the line using just one single coordinate: its distance from $p_0$, measured positively in one direction, and negatively in the other direction. That shows you *can* determine each point on the line using just one coordinate, so certainly the dimension is $\le $ 1. Convince yourself that you can't do it with less than one coordinate, and you'll get an intuitive proof of the intuitive fact that the line has dimension $1$.

Comment: Wow! this is a possible avenue I never even considered. I guess I have much to learn about geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a point on a line with 1 number the distance from the start of the line. The line is embedded in a 2d space so you can also specidy a point with 2 numbers. However we want the minimum number of numbers needed to specify the pointm therefore the line has dimension 1.

Comment: Interesting, so what you're saying is that an object such as a line or line segment can have more than one kind of coordinate, such as in this case: 1/coordinates coming from a position on a cartesian plane                              and/or:                                                                                                                             2/the distance from one point to another on a line segment (which can determine it to be a one-dimensional object) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Points do not have dimension. Spaces do. So your point $E$ belongs to a plane, thus it can be represented by two coordinates. But the same point happen to belong to a line, so it could be represented by a single coordinate referenced to a *basis* of the one-dimensional space. And, starting from that, you have the whole topic of linear algebra in front of you...

Comment: Yes, I can't wait to dive right in! Haha

Comment: @CinnabarToffee Maybe the name scares you but the accepted answer is nothing more (and nothing less) than linear algebra disguised as geometry.